# Oracle 10g SQL plus unkown username, password and Host string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, database-connection, sqlplus

I have just installed Oracle 10g database and also oracle developer suit, which is installed as DevSuiteHome1 in my computer. I could not use SQL plus because I dont know the exact username, password and host string to connect. During installation I did not ask to enter any username & password. Then what would be the username,password + host string? Help me out of this.

[image]

Comment: Why `Oracle 10g` in this century? If it is for learning purpose, and no cost involved, install `Oracle 12c`.

Comment: Are you certain that you created a database?  Rather than, say, installing the database software but not creating a database?  10g is ancient but it's not so old that you should be able to create a database without being prompted at least for the `sys` password.  I would guess that you don't actually have a database to connect to.  Is there a service OracleService<<SOMETHING>> in Control Panel?  Is there an entry in your tnsnames.ora file for the local database?  What does `lsnrctl status` return?

Answer (score 1):

> During installation I did not ask to enter any username & password.

You might have done a **client-only installation** and not the **database**. Database creation will definitely **prompt** you to enter these details.

> I dont know the exact username, password and host string to connect.

You can connect to the database locally using the combination of **ORACLE_HOME** and **ORACLE_SID** environment variables.

Depending on your **OS**:

**Unix/Linux:**

```
export ORACLE_HOME=<oracle_home_directory_till_db_home>
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export ORACLE_SID=<your_oracle_sid>
SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA
```

**Windows**

```
set ORACLE_HOME=<oracle_home_path_till_db_home>
set PATH=%PATH%||%ORACLE_HOME%\bin
set ORACLE_SID=<your_oracle_sid>
SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA
```

Once connected, you could then alter the user and modify the password.

```
ALTER USER username IDENTIFIED BY password;
```